# AttributeError: 'Corn' object has no attribute '_Plant__symbol'

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm having trouble with sub classes. our task was to use as much inheritance as possible. now I'm getting this error and obviously I must be doing something wrong.

What happens to `self.__symbol` if I want to call it from a sub class? I'm spawning 20 `Plant` objects and then each of them is meant to spawn an offspring.

What really confuses me is that it must have existed at some point since `__repr__` works fine as tested with my `#temporary` fix. How do I get it to remain callable without just redefining it in the sub's `__init__` - since that would defy the purpose of inheritance, wouldn't it? Is the way I'm extending with `super().performAction()` or the `super().__init__` maybe problematic? All tutorials suggest this approach.

```
class Thing:
    """ Represents all possible creatures in the world.
    """


    def __init__(self, symbol, x, y):
        """
        """
        self.__symbol = symbol
        self.__position = (x,y)
        self.__age = 0


    def __repr__(self):
        return (self.__symbol)

    #print ('debug: i am', self, '. I´m at', self.__position)
    def performAction(self, world):
        self.__age += 1
        pass

class Plant(Thing):
    """ Represents all possible plants in the world.
    """

    def __init__(self, symbol, x, y):
        super().__init__(symbol, x, y)
        self.__seedCycle = 6

    def performAction(self, world):
        super().performAction(world)
        self.__seedCycle -=1
        if self.__seedCycle <= 0:
            randomdirection = [(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0),(-1,0)]
            random.shuffle(randomdirection)
            for i in randomdirection:
                x = world.getPos(self)[0] + i[0]
                y = world.getPos(self)[1] + i[1]
                if world.getObject(x, y) == '.':
                    world.spawn(self.__symbol, x, y)
                    # temporary fix: world.spawn(str(self), x, y)
                    break
```

Comment: Why are you using `__leading_double_underscore` names? They're precisely *meant* to make access from subclasses difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Attributes with leading double underscores are meant to be 'private' and not accessible from other classes.

Python achieves this by putting the class name in front of the attribute, when you access it. This is why you get `_Plant__symbol` in the error message.
The easiest solution would be to rename the `__symbol` to something without two leading underscores to make it accessible from other classes.

The str() method works here, because it calls the Test objects `__repr__` method and the Test object can access its own 'private' attributes.